# Concatenate 2 dimensional list in a new list

Tags: python

I have list like this:

> My_list = [[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10],[11,12,13,14,15],[16,17,18,19,20]]

I want to make a new list like this:

> new_list =
>   [[1,2,3,9,10],[4,5,6,7,8],[11,12,13,19,20],[14,15,16,17,18]]

The first half of index 0 + the second half of index 1 and the reverse of this, but I have no idea how to do that.

Something like this:

> new_list[1][:3] + new_list[2][2:]

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code for your problem.

```
My_list = [[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10],[11,12,13,14,15],[16,17,18,19,20]]

n=len(My_list)

new_list=[[],[],[],[]]

for i in range(0,n-1,2):
    new_list[i]=My_list[i][:3]+My_list[i+1][3:]
    new_list[i+1]=My_list[i][3:]+My_list[i+1][:3]

print(new_list)
```

Comment: how i can append the for to the new_list??

Comment: You can use new_list.append() for that

Comment: new_list.append(My_list[i][:3]+My_list[i+1][3:])
_____________________________________________
new_list.append(My_list[i][3:]+My_list[i+1][:3])